# Does Ninject retrieve new unique instances per Get()

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, ninject

I am wondering if Ninject's kernel Get() function retrieve's one instanciated instance in the following snippet:

```
_kernel = new StandardKernel();
CreateBindings();

ICard card = _kernel.Get<ICard>();
ICard card2 = _kernel.Get<ICard>();
```

Does `card` and `card2` point to the same instance or do they point to two separate instances? Also, if I had an `ICard[]` and I wanted to fill the array with 10 unique instances of ICard, how can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on how binding for that type has been configured. If binding is singleton, both instances would be the same:

```
_kernel.Bind<ICard>().To<Card>().InSingletonScope();
```

However when you use default binding, both instances will be different:

```
_kernel.Bind<ICard>().To<Card>();
```

To fill array use the following code:

```
var array = Enumerable.Repeat(1, 10)
     .Select(_ => _kernel.Get<ICard>())
     .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 2):

Separate instances, it's an IOC framework, it's not a cache. Assuming ICard is implemented by a reference type, you can prove this by trying...

```
bool isSameInstance = card.Equals(card2);
```

Given this is true a for loop can be used to fill your array.

Comment: You seem to have ignored the concept of [scopes](https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Object-Scopes).

Comment: The binding I'm using is the default Transient binding, so I think dbugger's answer still applies.